# Kinect Depth FPS slows Significantly when Human Detected

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, frame-rate, depth

I have a application where I create my own Depth Frame (using the Kinect SDK). The problem is when a human is detected the FPS of the depth (and then the color too) slows down significantly. [Here](http://youtu.be/m09Pxz0yNpc) is a movie of when the frame slows down. The code I am using:

```
        using (DepthImageFrame DepthFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
        {
            depthFrame = DepthFrame;
            pixels1 = GenerateColoredBytes(DepthFrame);

            depthImage = BitmapSource.Create(
                depthFrame.Width, depthFrame.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, pixels1,
                depthFrame.Width * 4);

            depth.Source = depthImage;
        }

...

    private byte[] GenerateColoredBytes(DepthImageFrame depthFrame2)
    {
        short[] rawDepthData = new short[depthFrame2.PixelDataLength];
        depthFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(rawDepthData);

        byte[] pixels = new byte[depthFrame2.Height * depthFrame2.Width * 4];

        const int BlueIndex = 0;
        const int GreenIndex = 1;
        const int RedIndex = 2;


        for (int depthIndex = 0, colorIndex = 0;
            depthIndex < rawDepthData.Length && colorIndex < pixels.Length;
            depthIndex++, colorIndex += 4)
        {
            int player = rawDepthData[depthIndex] & DepthImageFrame.PlayerIndexBitmask;

            int depth = rawDepthData[depthIndex] >> DepthImageFrame.PlayerIndexBitmaskWidth;

            byte intensity = CalculateIntensityFromDepth(depth);
            pixels[colorIndex + BlueIndex] = intensity;
            pixels[colorIndex + GreenIndex] = intensity;
            pixels[colorIndex + RedIndex] = intensity;

            if (player > 0)
            {
                pixels[colorIndex + BlueIndex] = Colors.Gold.B;
                pixels[colorIndex + GreenIndex] = Colors.Gold.G;
                pixels[colorIndex + RedIndex] = Colors.Gold.R;
            }
        }

        return pixels;
    }
```

FPS is quite crucial to me since I am making an app that saves pictures of people when they are detected. How can I maintain a faster FPS? Why is my application doing this?

Comment: is this the windows kinect SDK code?

Comment: Try putting the intensity pixel setting in an 'else' after the player 'if'

Comment: @DanBryant Still has the same effect

Comment: Can you check your memory consumption? Its just a wild guess, but maybe your app is at one point starting to allocate to much memory and the garbage collector can't keep up. And just one idea, don't create a new bitmap all the time, reuse it or consider WriteableBitmap.

Comment: @dowhilefor So should I delete the BitmapSources after I am done with them? Also good idea with the WriteableBitmap, but when I have tried that with color images (which are incredibly more simple) it has not worked, and still slows some. This is the first time that it has happened. Other apps where I create a point cloud out of the depth data don't slow when a Person is detected.

Comment: I am not sure but I think there is somthing wrong with how you dispose objects in your using clause, I can see you are disposing the "DepthFrame" object but you allocating more objects like "depthImage" and "depthFrame", are those being disposed correct as well?

Comment: @G.Y depthFrame is being used elsewhere in code, and DepthImage is reassigned for every frame

Comment: @Outlaw, what if you use a WriteableBitmap with the WritePixels method instead of BitmapSource.Create ? So you don't create a new BitmapSource each time you get a new frame.

Also, for the arrays (rawDepthData and pixels), couldn't you initialize them just once with the right length when you enable the streams ?

Comment: @RenaudDumont Good thinking, I will try that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

G.Y is correct that you're not disposing properly. You should refactor your code so the DepthImageFrame is disposed of ASAP.

```
...
private short[] rawDepthData = new short[640*480]; // assuming your resolution is 640*480

using (DepthImageFrame depthFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
{
    depthFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(rawDepthData);
}

pixels1 = GenerateColoredBytes(rawDepthData);    
...

private byte[] GenerateColoredBytes(short[] rawDepthData){...}
```

You said that you're using the depth frame elsewhere in the application. This is bad. If you need some specific data from the depth frame, save it separately.

dowhilefor is also correct that you should look at using a WriteableBitmap, it's super simple.

```
private WriteableBitmap wBitmap;

//somewhere in your initialization
wBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(...);
depth.Source = wBitmap;

//Then to update the image:
wBitmap.WritePixels(...);
```

Also, you're creating new arrays to store pixel data again and again on every frame. You should create these arrays as global variables, create them a single time, and then just overwrite them on every frame.

Finally, although this shouldn't make a huge difference, I'm curious about your CalculateIntensityFromDepth method. If the compiler isn't inlining that method, that's a lot of extraneous method calls. Try to remove that method and just write the code where the method call is right now.

Comment: This is the same as I figured out. Thanks